# Linking Error in C++ on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, libs

Following error is coming when I am compiling the project "proj1" code which is using xyz.lib (it is a different project that got compiled successfully).

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Vsnprintf16(unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?Vsnprintf16@@YAHPAGIPBGPAD@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl eastl::Vsnprintf(wchar_t *,unsigned int,wchar_t const *,char *)" (?Vsnprintf@eastl@@YAHPA_WIPB_WPAD@Z)  File : xyz.lib(abc.obj)
```

abc.cpp has calls to function sprintf .

When I am moving all the code of abc.h and abc.cpp to some other lets say  def.h and def.cpp file which is already present in xyz project then all works fine, no linking error. I don't know why.

I have used all the includes that were used in file def.cpp in abc.cpp but same error.

When I am removing the sprintf() calls from abc.cpp then also all works fine.

Please if anyone can suggest why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: Is your project build with UNICODE enabled?

Comment: Yes I tried it with unicode macro enabled and disabled, same error. In project settings characterset is "Use Unicode character set" @marcinj

Comment: it is looks like you should add definition for this function yourself

Answer (score 2):

I have searched msdn and also VS2015 and VS2005 source code folders and found no definition or declaration of `Vsnprintf16`.

I have not used eastl but it looks like you should define this function by yourself, you can find examples in following links:

https://github.com/BSVino/Digitanks/blob/master/common/eastl.cpp

https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/test/source/main.cpp

for reference I include it here:

```
// EASTL also wants us to define this (see string.h line 197)
int Vsnprintf8(char* pDestination, size_t n, const char* pFormat, va_list arguments)
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        return _vsnprintf(pDestination, n, pFormat, arguments);
    #else
        return vsnprintf(pDestination, n, pFormat, arguments);
    #endif
}

int Vsnprintf16(char16_t* pDestination, size_t n, const char16_t* pFormat, va_list arguments)
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        return _vsnwprintf((wchar_t*)pDestination, n, (wchar_t*)pFormat, arguments);
    #else
        char* d = new char[n+1];
        int r = vsnprintf(d, n, convertstring<char16_t, char>(pFormat).c_str(), arguments);
        memcpy(pDestination, convertstring<char, char16_t>(d).c_str(), (n+1)*sizeof(char16_t));
        delete[] d;
        return r;
    #endif
}
```

Comment: But sprintf is getting used in lot of files only for that file only it is giving linking error. And if I move the code of this file into another, everything works fine. Code is getting the definition of the function you mentioned, but for abc.cpp file the compilation is not happening properly. Why ? thats the question. I currently made the code work by moving the code of abc.cpp file into another file. @marcinj

Comment: So you have definition of Vsnprintf16 in your project application? Or maybe its present in this xyz.lib? Maybe check whether abc.cpp has any individual configuration / options set which are different from this def.cpp. Maybe some special Preprocessor Definitions.

Comment: He doesn't mention how he builds the eastl, but it is possible that he doesn't link in `eastl.cpp`... I don't know the eastl well enough. But well done to you on get this answer out; that is some research effort.

Comment: abc.cpp and def.cpp have same properties. I checked every property. @marcinj